# OpenMP loop where each iteration depends on previous

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

So I have a small loop that I'm trying to parallelize using OpenMP. The problem I'm facing is that each iteration depends on the result from the previous one. Look at my code below:

```
for(int i=1; i < N; i++) {

    for(int j=0; j < M; j++) {

        A[i][j] = A[i-1][j];

        if(x[i] <= j)
            A[i][j] += A[i-1][j-x[i]];

    }

}
```

As you can see, my output depends on the result from previous input from `A[i][j]`. Another thing to note is that I have the `A[0][j]` initialized before I enter the loop.

Can someone please help me on how to go about doing this?

EDIT: I know you have to use `#pragma omp parallel for` for loops but in this case i'm pretty sure my program won't work correctly.

Comment: what does `x` look like? E.g. is it sorted? Is it sparse? What is the range? What is it?

Comment: Please provide a representative [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parallelize the outermost loop as is. Each thread needs to "own" a section of the array otherwise you will introduce races.

As you mentioned, there is a data dependency from iteration i to iteration i-1. Each iteraton of the loop could happen in any order and such a dependency introduces a race.

```
Step 1
T0                   T1
i=1                  i=2
A[1][j] = A[0][j]    A[2] = A[1][j]
// T0 writes to A[1][j] while T1 reads A[1][j]
```

The inner loop can be made parallel assuming A is in the shape `A[N][M]`. In that case, only 2 rows in A will be accesses at a time, i and i-1. There is no longer a data dependency because the j loop is being made parallel and not i.

Comment: The inner loop still as a dependency I think due to `j-x[i]`.